# SwiftUI ScrollView how to scroll on tvOS with long Text

Tags: swiftui, scrollview, tvos

I need to render a long text, how to wrap it with ScrollView and then slide it vertically? (tvOS)

I tried the following code, i can focus on it by adding `.focusable()` to `Text`, but it cannot slide smoothly, it will go straight to the end.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let longlongText = Array(repeating: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.", count: 20).joined()
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                Button("Hello, world!") {}
                
                Text(longlongText)
                    .focusable()
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

[image: tvOS Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I'm a super beginner and I came across the same problem. I managed to implement this thanks to https://qiita.com/abouch/items/8fa4c8e7777fd4ed37db though I still don't understand how View and UIView work together.

```
struct TextView: UIViewRepresentable {
  @Binding var attributedText: NSAttributedString
  @Binding var offset: Int

  func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(self)
  }
  
  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
    let textView = UITextView()
    textView.delegate = context.coordinator
    textView.isScrollEnabled = true
    textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    textView.backgroundColor = .clear
    return textView
  }
  
  func updateUIView(_ textView: UITextView, context: Context) {
    textView.attributedText = attributedText
    textView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: offset*10), animated: true)
  }
}

extension TextView {
  final class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
    private var textView: TextView
    
    init(_ textView: TextView) {
      self.textView = textView
    }
    
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
      return true
    }
    
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
      self.textView.attributedText = textView.attributedText
    }
  }
}
```

Initializing in SwiftUI is like this:

```
TextView(attributedText:$longText, offset:$offset)
```

Add up and down buttons on the view, then increment/decrement offset triggered by the button action to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

For me the following code worked in tvos

```
    [_textView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [_textView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [_textView setSelectable:YES];
    _textView.panGestureRecognizer.allowedTouchTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:UITouchTypeIndirect], nil];
```

for swift use

````
    textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true;
    textView.isScrollEnabled = true;
    textView.selectable = true;
    textView.panGestureRecognizer.allowedTouchTypes = [NSNumber(value: UITouch.TouchType.indirect.rawValue)]```
````